# ModelService does not remove the model in groovy script

Tags: database, groovy, crud, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm trying to remove a model from database using ModelService in my groovy script but it doesn't remove.

```
import de.hybris.platform.core.model.order.OrderModel
import de.hybris.platform.ordersplitting.model.ConsignmentModel

List<String> orderList = new ArrayList<>()
orderList.add("P000015003")

OrderModel orderModel = flexibleSearchService.search(String.format("SELECT {PK} FROM {AbstractOrder} WHERE {code} = '%s'", "P000015003")).result.get(0)
ConsignmentModel consignment = orderModel.getConsignments().iterator().next()
ModelService modelService = (ModelService) spring.getBean("modelService");
modelService.remove(consignment)
println("Removed")
```

Comment: It looks like you updated the title with the word "SOLVED" but you didn't provide the solution.  You should post the solution if you have solved it, accept an answer, or delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the 'commit' mode is ON as shown in the image below?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use transaction to perform commit operation:

```
import de.hybris.platform.core.model.order.OrderModel
import de.hybris.platform.ordersplitting.model.ConsignmentModel

def tx = de.hybris.platform.tx.Transaction.current()

tx.begin()

List<String> orderList = new ArrayList<>()
orderList.add("P000015003")

OrderModel orderModel = flexibleSearchService.search(String.format("SELECT {PK} FROM {AbstractOrder} WHERE {code} = '%s'", "P000015003")).result.get(0)
ConsignmentModel consignment = orderModel.getConsignments().iterator().next()
ModelService modelService = (ModelService) spring.getBean("modelService");
modelService.remove(consignment)
println("Removed") 


tx.commit()
```